# Calling a C# method from .js file

Tags: javascript, c#

I have a aspx page and in that i have method `UpdateScreenAlertStatus();`

I want to have a file called dtml.js and in that i have function `openmodelpopup()`.

I want to call `UpdateScreenAlertStatus();` in javscript method `openmodelpopup()`.

Comment: What C#? Are you using Web Forms? MVC? please specify

Comment: There are different ways to call server side methods from client code, but none of them are just a simple method call. What is it that the `UpdateScreenAlertStatus` does? Judging from the name, you are trying to do something that's not possible to do from a method called by client code.

Comment: UpdateScreenAlertStatus() is your code behind method that you want to invoke in js?Is that what you want?

Comment: To call a C# method from javascript you need to make it remotely callable over http, few options are [1] web api [2] mvc [3] aspx web methods [4] wcf

Comment: yes UpdateScreenAlertStatus is in my code behind and i want to invoke in .js fle

Comment: its a aspx page in that UpdateScreenAlertStatus () is there

Comment: i cannot make that method as webmethod

Answer (score 2):

```
function MyMethod() {
    $.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "abc.aspx/UpdateScreenAlertStatus ",
    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
    dataType: "json"
    });
}
```

Call the above ajax in your js function openmodelpopup().

```
[WebMethod]
public static void UpdateScreenAlertStatus()
{....}
```

Answer (score 1):

Make it a web method

```
[WebMethod]
public static string UpdateScreenAlertStatus()
{....}
```

Refer [this](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.services.webmethodattribute(v=vs.110).aspx) MSDN article.

From javascript you can access this as `YourPage.aspx/UpdateScreenAlertStatus` or through `PageMethods` in same aspx page. You can call this with the following javascript.

```
function openmodelpopup() {
    $.ajax
         ({
             type: "POST",
             contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
             url: "YourPage.aspx/UpdateScreenAlertStatus",
             success: (function (data) {
                 $("#statusDiv").text(data.d);
                 $("#statusDiv").show();
             }),
             error: (function () {
                 alert("Error occurred in server!");
             })
         });
}
```

I'm assuming here, 1. your C# method is `static` and marked `WebMethod`. 2. Code is compiled properly. 3. You are using jQuery. 4. The url in javascript is correct. 5. Your C# method returns a string status. 6. You are trying to update html element `statusDiv` with that string.

Comment: but its .js file i used PageMethod is throwing undefined error

Comment: Check the code and conditions in the updated answer.

Comment: guys no luck i added page method in .js file and called that method still its throwing undefined error from .js file

Comment: @user3675493 maybe it's time you posted your code so we can see what you're doing wrong

Comment: function OpenModalReplyDialog(url, SubscriberId) {
    
    var returnValue = new ModalReturnValue(null, null, null);
    var retVal = null;
    var urlredirect = url + '/UC_5_0_0.aspx?SubscriberId=' + SubscriberId;
    PageMethods.set_path(urlredirect);
    PageMethods.UpdateScreenAlertStatus(XtTypes.EnumScreenAlertStatusType.Acknowledged);
    returnValue = openModal(urlredirect, 350, 500);
    return true;
} this is .js file